# Measurement of the quantum observable by different instruments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, measurements, quantum-measurements

In the standard interpretation, the measurement of a quantum observable leads to the collapse of the wave function and obtaining a certain value of the observable. In some cases, further measurement of the same quantum observable will give the same result. Even if the subsequent measurements were performed with a different but identical device.

What is the physical interpretation of this? During the measurement, the quantum system S becomes entangled with the measuring device D1. Further, by measuring the same system S with the device D2, we obtain the same value of the observed quantity. What is it like? The system also gets entangled with the second device, but why is the result the same? Because the D1 device was already entangled with the larger environment (laboratory and other devices, including the D2 device)?

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "standard interpretation". If you mean common graduate textbooks, there is no interpretation or explanation, it is just assumed that the state of apparatus+system is entangled in such a way that in  each term the "pointer" coincides with the value of the observable, regardless of the number of measurements. If you mean something like von Neumman QM its close, maybe coherence can help. Some texts state the orthodox interpretation as the "standard" then it depends on the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Copenhagen Interpretation as formalised by John von Neumann is that when you make a measurement of an observable associated with a particle whose wave function is not an eigenfunction of that observable, the wave function of the particle changes as a consequence of the measurement to become an eigenfunction of the observable, namely an eigenfunction associated with the eigenvalue detected by the device.

Once its wave function has been caused to become an eigenfunction of the observable, successive measurements will continue to yield the same result.

The standard interpretation doesn't attempt to dig any deeper to say what is happening in the interaction between particle and measuring devices to cause the wave function to change during the first measurement and not during the subsequent ones.

Answer (score 1):

It is a postulate that subsequent measurement of the same physical quantity will give same result regardless of the measuring device. If this is not so, we have to identitfy both the measured quantity and the measuring device for a theoretical description. However, if two devices give different result after subsequent measurement, we can say (and we indeed say) that they measure different quantity, since it is not part of the theory which device corresponds to which quantity  and different quantities can be measured with the same device. So,  this is related with the meaning (or definition) of the sentence "these two device measure the same quantity".

However, as L. Landau says in his book on quantum theory, *All the measuring device are governed by classical mechanics.* I do not think so the entanglement of the measuring device with the system under observation has meaning, provided that you admit the Copenhagen Interpration.

Comment: What is the physical interpretation? During the measurement, the particle got entangled with instrument A. But with instrument B it is not entangled. How can a further measurement with instrument B give the same answer? Due to decoherence, since device A is entangled with the environment, including device B?

Comment: Are you asking motivation behind the postulate?

Comment: No, I'm asking about the physical mechanisms that ensure that two different devices get the same result. In the context of system entanglement with a device and decoherence.

Answer (score -2):

Arman Armenpress,

Entanglement just means correlation. It's not some magical property.

When an electron enters a Stern-Gerlach device, its spin is forced to align with the instrument's magnetic field. This is what "entangled" means in this situation. Since we know the orientation of the instrument we also know the orientation of the electron's spin.

Other similarly oriented Stern-Gerlach devices will be therefore also "entangled" with the electron. They will have no effect on the electron since its spin is already aligned with their field.

Comment: Entanglement also means that the state is not separable, that is, it is already a single quantum system.

Comment: A Stern-Gerlach device is not a quantum system, or, more exactly, its "quantum" character is irrelevant. The uncertainty regarding its state is practically 0. Without uncertainty there can be no superposition and therefore no entanglement In fact, I think that the idea that a measurement results in an entangled system-instrument state is wrong. The measurement collapses the state to a classical state.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you think. The orthodox interpretation is simply not interested in such "little things" as decoherence and entanglement. But interpretations that clarify and expand Copenhagen take this into account. And in them the measuring device gets entangled with the system.

Comment: What interpretations that "clarify and expand" Copenhagen do you have in mind?

Comment: Consistent histories, Quantum Darwinism, Relational quantum mechanics, etc.

Comment: Take a look at this paper by Griffiths "What Quantum Measurements Measure", Chapter IV C Nondestructive Measurements and Preparations: "A measurement determines a past property whereas a preparation is a procedure to prepare a particular quantum state, and a nondestructive measurement combines the two: the apparatus both measures and prepares certain properties" So, the first measurement prepares the particle in a spin UP on Z state and all other Z-oriented instruments would simply record that property, like I said. No entangled particle/instrument state is obtained.

Comment: Quantum Darwinism is wrong as it assumes the existence of macroscopic superposed states. No such states can exist, they were never prepared and never will be prepared. Their state is always well-defined since they are in constant interaction (gravitational, electromagnetic) with the environment. Those interactions cannot be stopped/shielded in any way since that would lead to charge/mass-energy non-conservation.

Comment: Relational quantum mechanics is a joke. Their "explanation" of EPR is nonsense. Just try to make sense of it!

Comment: I apologize, but I have to repeat: your personal opinion is absolutely irrelevant. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, I've presented you with an exact quote from one of your preferred interpretations, consistent histories. This is not my opinion, it's a fact. My claims were correct, yours wrong. I agree however that trying to reason with you is a lost of my time. You should not ask questions if you already know the answer.

Comment: You call your own opinion a fact (Quantum Darwinism is wrong, Relational quantum mechanics is a joke), and you want your words to be taken seriously. But this is unreal. You don’t understand decoherence, you don’t understand quantum entanglement, but you are making loud statements. That's funny. That is why I say: the fact that you are on the side of the orthodox interpretation does not make you right.

Comment: Consistent histories: Ive given you the relevant quote; Quantum Darwinism: can you provide any evidence of entangled states for macroscopic objects? I have also explained why they can't happen. Entanglement is a sort of superposition state. Superposition requires uncertainty. The state of an instrument pointer is certain, hence no superposition and no entanglement.

Comment: Relational quantum mechanics: can't explain EPR! If you disagree just present the explanation here!

Comment: I will have to advise you to familiarize yourself with the pioneering work of Zurek, as well as the work of Rovelli and Griffiths. Along with this, read about decoherence, at least at the Wikipedia level. I have nothing more to say to you. All the best